# Implement axis parameter in a custom function

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm writing a rather trivial function to perform an integration applying trapezoidal rule in log space.

I'd like to add the axis parameter to achieve a functionality similar to the `numpy.trapz` function, but I'm a bit confused regarding how to correctly implement it.

The non-broadcastable function looks like:

```
import numpy as np

def logtrapz(y, x):

    logx = np.log(x)
    dlogx = np.diff(logx)

    logy = np.log(y)
    dlogy = np.diff(logy)

    b = dlogx + dlogy
    a = np.exp(logx + logy)

    dF = a[:-1] * (np.exp(b) - 1)/b * dlogx

    return np.sum(dF)
```

this works fine for 1D inputs.

I think the solution lies in `numpy.expand_dims`, but I'm not really sure how to implement it

Comment: You can read the Python code for both `np.trapz` and `np.expand_dims`.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm doing it right now, but there are some passages that use almost undocumented features. In particular, lines 4059 to 4064 of `np.trapz` source code ( https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.1/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L4059 )use `slice(None)` which is not documented in the official slice documentation.

Comment: `slice(None)` produces a slice object, `slice(None,None,None)` which is the same as `[:]` or `[::]` in indexing notation.  That's a kind of detail that one picks up more from experience than from documentation.  Trying out bits of code in an interactive is essential for this kind of code reading and development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this copying the approach that is used in `numpy.trapz`. This is a bit convoluted, but it worked quite well.

For future readers, the broadcastable version of the above function is

```
import numpy as np

def logtrapz(y, x, axis=-1):

    x = np.asanyarray(x)
    logx = np.log(x)
    if x.ndim == 1:
        dlogx = np.diff(logx)
        # reshape to correct shape
        shape1 = [1]*y.ndim
        shape1[axis] = dlogx.shape[0]
        shape2 = [1]*y.ndim
        shape2[axis] = logx.shape[0]
        dlogx = dlogx.reshape(shape1)
        logx  = logx.reshape(shape2)
    else:
        dlogx = np.diff(x, axis=axis)

    nd = y.ndim
    slice1 = [slice(None)]*nd
    slice2 = [slice(None)]*nd
    slice1[axis] = slice(None, -1)
    slice2[axis] = slice(1, None)
    slice1 = tuple(slice1)
    slice2 = tuple(slice2)

    logy = np.log(y)
    dlogy = logy[slice2] - logy[slice1]

    b = dlogx + dlogy
    a = np.exp(logx + logy)

    dF = a[slice1] * (np.exp(b) - 1)/b * dlogx

    np.sum(dF, axis=axis)
```

To achieve "broadcastability" a mix of `reshape` and `slice` are employed, explicitly creating "shape" vectors with the desired output shape.

I was thinking this could be achieved with a much shorter and neater way, but apparently this is the way is implemented in numpy itself.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate the `slice` exploration in an interactive session:

```
In [216]: slice(None)                                                           
Out[216]: slice(None, None, None)
In [217]: slice??                                                               
Init signature: slice(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:     
slice(stop)
slice(start, stop[, step])

Create a slice object.  This is used for extended slicing (e.g. a[0:10:2]).
Type:           type
Subclasses:     
In [218]: np.s_[:]                                                              
Out[218]: slice(None, None, None)
```

I haven't looked at the `np.trapz` code, but I know other `numpy` functions often construct indexing tuples when they need to be `axis` general.

For example a generalized indexing of a 3d array:

```
In [221]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)                                    
In [223]: idx = [slice(None) for _ in range(3)]                                 
In [224]: idx                                                                   
Out[224]: [slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None)]
In [225]: idx[1]=1                                                              
In [226]: idx                                                                   
Out[226]: [slice(None, None, None), 1, slice(None, None, None)]
In [227]: tuple(idx)                                                            
Out[227]: (slice(None, None, None), 1, slice(None, None, None))
In [228]: arr[tuple(idx)]     # arr[:,1,:]                                                  
Out[228]: 
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])
In [229]: idx[2]=2                                                              
In [230]: arr[tuple(idx)]     # arr[:,1,2]                                                  
Out[230]: array([ 6, 18])
```

Comment: I really thank you for your explanation of `slice(None)`, but I can't really say that this is an answer to my question.